# How to get Apache2 to wait for network initialization?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, apache-http-server

Server just upgraded from Squeeze to Wheezy. After reboots, I noted that apache2 wasn't starting, so installed bootlogd to inspect the output of init scripts.

The error output from apache start was,

```
Tue Feb  3 08:49:55 2015: [....] Starting web server: apache2(99)Cannot assign requested address: make_sock: could not bind to address [0123:4567:890:abc::d]:80
Tue Feb  3 08:49:55 2015: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Tue Feb  3 08:49:55 2015: Unable to open logs
Tue Feb  3 08:49:55 2015: Action 'start' failed.
Tue Feb  3 08:49:55 2015: The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Timestamps in the boot output show 4s between "Configuring network interfaces" (08:49:51) and starting apache.

I've worked around this by inserting a `sleep 5` into `/etc/init.d/apache2` after which apache2 starts fine, so I'm reading it as slow network initialization (possibly specific to IPv6 networking). The server is running on VMWare, and I have access only to the VM.

- What better methods could I use to make Apache wait a few seconds and check its addresses are up and running before start?
- Or to make the network init script not exit until the addresses are ready?

Comment: Network init because Apache's init output complains about inability to grab the address ... *unless* delayed by a few seconds. Only one Apache install present via stock Debian packages, no other services on port 80/443.

Comment: Still facing this issue in 2020. I have a bunch of lines of `up ip addr add 1.2.3...` and It's causing delays. Apache and Nginx won't start (when listening to specific IPs), while Gitlab (using Nginx under it's own Omnibus package) can listen to another IP. Because the starting process does cost some time.

Answer (score 1):

> What better methods could I use to make Apache wait a few seconds and
>   check its addresses are up and running before start?

Well, the method I am outlining obviously does not solve the underlying issue. But I believe using a stand-alone monitoring tool that can handle the “kicking Apache into service” task without having to hack the `init.d` script is a more stable solution. The key is to use [`monit`](http://mmonit.com/monit/) which is self-described as:

> Monit is a small Open Source utility for managing and monitoring Unix
>   systems. Monit conducts automatic maintenance and repair and can
>   execute meaningful causal actions in error situations.

To install it in Ubuntu, just do this; I am using `aptitude` and this is on Ubuntu 12.04 FWIW:

```
sudo aptitude install monit
```

Once installed I like to setup the default mail server for sending out alerts. This assumes you have `postfix` or `sendmail` active on your server. Open up the `monit` control file with your favorite text editor; I like to use `nano`:

```
sudo nano /etc/monit/monitrc
```

Look for the `set mailserver` lines and set this line and save the `monit` control file:

```
set mailserver localhost
```

Now check and make sure there is a `monit` `conf.d` directory setup; this is where individual `monit` tasks are setup:

```
ls -la /etc/monit/conf.d
```

If somehow that `/etc/monit/conf.d` was not set up, create it like this:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/monit/conf.d
```

Now with that done, let’s create a `monit` Apache ruleset. First, figure out where the Apache `.pid` file is set and check that it is set. This is usually where it is set on Ubuntu 12.04 using the default Apache package install:

```
ls -la /var/run/apache2.pid
```

If that `.pid` filepath is correct, let’s create the actual `monit` Apache ruleset with `nano` like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/monit/conf.d/apache2.conf
```

And place this code in that file and save it:

```
check process apache with pidfile /var/run/apache2.pid
        start "/etc/init.d/apache2 start"
        stop  "/etc/init.d/apache2 stop"
        if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 80
                with timeout 15 seconds
        then restart
        alert YourEmail@example.com only on { timeout, nonexist }
```

The logic to the script is fairly simple: The `monit` Apache ruleset will check the `/var/run/apache2.pid` file and it knows to use specific `init.d` directives for `start` and `stop` logic.  The magic comes from the `if`/`then` block which basically monitors Apache port `80` on localhost `127.0.0.1` and will take action to recover Apache if there is a timeout of 15 seconds or more. And the `alert` line will send e-mail alerts to a specified e-mail address if the conditions of `timeout` or `nonexist` are met; that is optional so feel free to comment that out if you don’t have the need to be flooded by e-mail alerts.

Now restart `monit`:

```
sudo service monit restart
```

And you can follow the `monit` log here to see it do it’s thing and debug it if something doesn’t work as expected:

```
sudo tail -f -n 200 /var/log/monit.log
```

So when the dust settles on that server, you will have `monit` setup to make sure Apache is running. Very useful as a general “keep the Apache web server alive” tool, but in your case `monit` can take over the task of making sure Apache comes up on reboot/startup so you don’t have to muck around with core Apache `init.d` script which is really a bit messy and is easily forgotten in the future during an upgrade.

Also note, I can see that you are binding Apache explicitly to IPv6, but this monitoring script assumes that if it can’t reach `127.0.0.1` then it should take action. Maybe you need to change the IPv4 localhost address of `127.0.0.1` to the IPv6 equivalent of address of `::1`. Experiment and see what works.